# Anzograph - Error - Insufficient memory for query:Out of memory

Tags: graph-databases

I am trying to get Anzograph (in Docker) to create some inferences from about 20.000 triplets and a very small ontology (13 classes, and 10 or so properties). I keep getting this error messages: "Error - Insufficient memory for query:Out of memory", although I think there is plenty of RAM available for Docker (12G). Is there any way to learn what goes awry?

Thank you in advance!

Regards,

Attila

Answer (score 0):

If you look at it's web console, you can see how much RAM AnzoGraph DB thinks it has available for it to use in your environment.

Comment: I checked it, it says: 0.265 GB out of 9.688 GB.  I also checked Docker with 'docker status' while running the query, Mem usage never goes above 2.5 GiB while the availabe RAM is 11.7 GiB.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like that should be plenty. Please can you take an x-ray immediately after experiencing the error and post it to the support ticket. Instructions are here https://docs.cambridgesemantics.com/anzograph/bp/support.htm

Thank you.